# Installing 12.04 on a system with windows 7 and UEFI

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 (64bits) next to a windows 7 preinstalled system.
I have found some troubles during the process.

Windows 7 partitions are like shown in figure [a link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/45nxzwpn2cngz9e/Captura.PNG

My idea was, during the Ubuntu installation, re-size the OS partition, allocating there windows and the "/" root folder, and make the data partition my new "/home" folder.

The problem is that when I boot Ubuntu live CD (or USB) both in EFI or MBR mode, in the partitioning step no partitions are detected in the disk. So, Ubuntu does not recognize the windows 7 partitions.

How can I install Ubuntu, without reinstalling windows 7? (Is a new notebook and I don't have all the drivers in the marker web).

Thanks a lot for your help

[Update]
Here are 2 screenshots from gparted and fdisk -l (running the live usb)
[a link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/d508aj61gvndt84/Screenshot%20from%202012-05-12%2011%3A39%3A25.png
[a link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5p83udaqqogqc1/Screenshot%20from%202012-05-12%2009%3A40%3A54.png

Comment: The image links are dead.  Can you update?

Answer (score 3):

The screen-shot links are dead; however, the usual cause of the symptoms as described is a corrupted partition table. If this computer is booting in BIOS mode (it may be, even if the firmware is UEFI-enabled), then my [FixParts utility](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) *may* be able to fix the problem pretty painlessly, but I can't make any promises about that. If the computer is booting in EFI mode, then I can't make any recommendations about fixes without more information. The output of `gdisk -l 0:` from Windows might help, but you'll need to install the Windows version of my [GPT fdisk](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) utility.

Comment: Finally I had to re-create the partition table, so I lost the windows 7 partition (and all the drivers).
I have also checked your app and is very useful! I would take into account for future uses